# Excel - Finding the next day that is not in a list

Tags: excel

I have a list of dates (School Holidays) in chronological order. I'd like to give it a date, and have the formula return the next day that is NOT in the list.

This is my list of dates:

```
January 1
January 2
January 3
January 28
February 11
February 15 etc
```

January 1 should return January 4
January 27 on the other hand, should return January 27 (because it's not on the list)
January 28 should return January 29, etc

I've looked and looked, but can't seem to find anything related to this. Do I need to do something in VBA? Or is there an easier way using just functions?

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2010 or later versions you can use `WORKDAY.INTL` function, e.g. with your holiday dates in `A1:A20` and your reference date in `D1`

`=WORKDAY.INTL(D1-1,1,"0000000",$A$1:$A$20)`

That uses `D1-1` and finds the next "working day" after that, with "0000000" defining all days as working days (except the holidays listed in A1:A20), so that may be D1 itself or the next non-holiday after that

Comment: Interesting. I looked at that function before, and didn't realize that on top of defining the normal working days (in the 0000000) part, that you could ALSO define other days on top of that. Great! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write a VBA Function.

Steps:

1: Name the range of holidays. Do this by selecting the holiday column, and entering "Holidays" in the name box.

[image: Excel Name Box]

2: Display the VBA editor by pressing alt+F11

3: In VBA: Insert > Module

[image: Excel Insert Module]

4: Enter this code

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NextSchoolDay(StartDate As Date)

Dim Holidays As Range
Set Holidays = Range("Holidays")

NextSchoolDay = StartDate
Do
    NextSchoolDay = NextSchoolDay + 1
Loop Until Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(CLng(NextSchoolDay), Holidays, 0))

End Function
```

5: You can now use the formula =NextSchoolDay(Date)

[image: Excel NextSchoolDay Formula]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer/tutorial. Thanks so much! While the other answer seems a little simpler, this answer expands in an interesting direction for future applications. Thanks so much Edward!

Comment: The other answer is a better solution to this - I didn't know about "workday" function. You should also mark that one as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time using stackoverflow. You both have been really helpful. I wish I had more rep so that I could give you guys 'kudos' or whatever ;) Guess I'll have to use my limited knowledge to help someone else. Thanks again!